# How to start to drive a multi-color LED?

Tags: microcontroller, led, pic

I wish to design a circuit that uses one button to turn on a multi-color LED to a preselected color, and then uses repeated button presses of another button to cycle the LED through 2 or 3 colors. In addition, the ability to flash the LED would be useful.

I'd be pleased to receive suggestions re means of achieving this task - either suitable components or ideas re suitable circuits or general guidance.

I'd also like to investigate using a microcontroller for this task. As I'm new to this area, I'd be grateful if people can advise me whether any particular uCs may be easier or best able to be used for this task.

Comment: @Nurul A CD4017 will step through 10 outputs as an LED sequencer. adding a timer square wave to the enable pin will make the selected LED flash. A 555 timer could be used to do this. You will also need a "clock" to clock the IC - another 555 will do that job. [**MANY ideas here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=led+sequencer&biw=1536&bih=860&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=NvFQVLGhA8-k8AW43YGQBg&ved=0CCQQsAQ)  | ANY PIC will do this easily - the limitation being the number of I/O pins on the PIC if you use no other ICs.

Comment: Nurul - My comment above re using a second 555 as a clock was wrong as you will be using a switch to "clock" or step the circuit. If a "4017" sequencer  is used it should be the sort with a Schmitt trigger on the clock input. A widely available HEF4017B from NXP semiconductors [data sheet here](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4017B.pdf) has a Schmitt trigger on the clock inputs. | I said above that the  4017 had an enable input that could be used for LED flashing, but I was wrong. If we start to talk about this circuit properly here we can provide advice in LED flashing.

Comment: [Manually operated LED sequencer circuit here](http://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/61040-how-to-build-a-simple-led-light-chaser-circuit/) is exactly what you want for basic sequencing. || [THIS DIAGRAM](http://www.electronicspoint.com/attachments/4017-555-2-gif.6175/) shows how to use transistors to get more LED drive. A resistor is needed in the collector circuit to 5V. | [Excellent related discussion](http://www.electronicspoint.com/threads/led-sequencer-scanner.254172/)

Answer (score 3):

To control something like an RGB LED with a few switches- there are cheaper micros, but I'd suggest something like a PIC16F628 because it's available in DIP, has a reasonable number of I/O port pins, and there is plenty of code available on the net that will allow you to get started (eg. blink a single LED).

Comment: is it same with PIC16F877A ?

Comment: Another popular one, yes.